# Syntax error when trying to cut part of a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

If I write a simple `echo $i`, I have no problem: it shows me the variable. But if I try do something with it

```
$($i|cut -d"." -f1-3)
```

then I get an error messages

```
: -bash: /...file.backup: Permission denied (in root env)
```

Can someone show me the way to solve it?

```
for i in $(find  /directory -type f -name '*.backup')
do 
  echo $i $($i|cut -d"." -f1-3)
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed out an echo before the $i

```
for i in $(find /directory -type f -name '*.backup')
do 
echo $i $(echo "$i"|cut -d"." -f1-3)
done`
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `basename` and or substrings?

See `man basename` and http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html for details on the substrings.

Using basename you can get the first portion of the filename ie. `basename $i ".backup"` will strip .backup from the filename.

And ${i::-7} wills strip the last 7 characters from the variable.

Comment: ${i::-7} -don' works for me "-bash: -7: substring expression < 0" but
${i/.backup} do

Answer (score -1):

Solved it in two loops. May be it's not optimal, but works. If anybody know other solution - let us know.

```
for i in $(find  /directory -type f -name '*.backup')
do 
    for j in $(find  /directory -type f -name '*.backup'|cut -d"." -f1-3)
    do 
        echo $i $j 
    done 
done
```

Comment: There is not need for two loops in here. It can be done within the same loop.